# Warning: Cannot modify header information when using require or require_once

Tags: wordpress

I'm WordPress newbie.

I'm creating a plugin that redirect to custom login page each unregistered user access a website, let say the custom login page : custom_login.php.

I am able to create a code to redirect it but it seems no wordpress functions work in custom_login.php. So, I think I have to load something through the file. I guess wp-load.php.

Then I add some codes below at the top of the page :

```
<?php
require( 'd:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php' );
?>
```

But then I got this error :
Warning: Cannot modify header information.....

I changed to require_once but still get similar error.

Some solutions of this forum threads advice to delete any whitespace. Frankly, I don't know what does it mean but I tried to delete all whitespace anyway so that the code become :

```
<?php require('d:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php');?>
```

But it does not solve anything. The error is still exist.

Please help me, the expert ones.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting a system path relative to localhost, like this:

```
require( '/wp-load.php' ); // or just
require( 'wp-load.php' ); //
```

All depends on the location you are trying to include wp-load.php from.

On the other hand, you don't have to include wp-load.php if you place the file custom_login.php. in the stylesheet directory as a template or as a custom page. The way to do it is:

.1 Rename the file to page-custom-login.php

.2 Move the file to the stylesheet directory (The theme directory)

.3 Go to admin and create a new page with the title "custom login"

That's all. Now WP will treat that file as a single custom page.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put the file in a plugin directory. Recently I copy wp-login.php, renamed it and put in the directory. I deleted all codes except require(...). Such error has been disappeared but another error raise : This webpage has a redirect loop. My goal is I can utilize Wordpress funtions within the file.

Comment: You renamed the file and **put in the directory**. ¿Which directory, the plugin directory?  What do you mean with **webpage has a redirect loop**, in htaccess or in a file? Yes, you should be able to use WP functions in any file, depending on it's location. If it is in the plugin directory, you will still have to load WP by including wp-load.php.

Comment: the directory is in wp-content/plugins/my-plugin. There is no .htaccess. This is what I'm trying to do : each time user open the website, my plugin check the login status. The plugin will open my own login page if he has not been logged in. I didn't use auth_redirect() because it brings to Wordpress login page default. I put the custom login page in the same folder of the plugin file. I noticed that the Wordpress functions are not recognized in the file so I think I have to include a Wordpress file within it. I use require function to include wp-load.php but get the error.

Comment: OK. Do what I suggested in my answer. Move the custom login page to the theme directory and rename it exactly as described. Must have the prefix "page-" for WP to recognize it. Create a page with title "custom login" and then you can access it like this: `MyDomain.com/custom-login`. If you leave it in the plugin directory you won't have access to WP functions, unless wp-load.php is loaded or the file is registered as a menu or submenu page for a plugin.

Comment: As long as I know, your suggestion will valid only a specific theme, right? I prefer to site wide so any theme can use it. Second thing is I need to put few query arguments, such as redirect_to, action (login or register), and so forth. I have no idea how to put the query arguments in the page. I think it is not solution I'm looking for. It would be great if you can share any references to solve such problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I understand, believe me. I have faced similar problems creating plugins with pages in the frontend. However, all WP themes are located in the /themes directory, so my suggestion is not for a specific theme, it applies to any theme and the purpose is to make visible the custom login page to WP. Hope you get the right answer anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

They are correct - you have a space before the opening php tag in one of your files.  It can be a bit tricky to find, but look hard.

If you can't find it, try looking for ob_clean() php function to help.